# git three-way diff using meld

Tags: git, diff

In git, I have already merged two branches, but I would like to 3-way diff the two (already) merged branches along with their ancestor (3-way diff). Is there a way to do this? Note that I don't want to undo the merge, just inspect the differences.

I prefer to use meld for to view the differences, if possible.

Comment: Probably not. Last I knew Meld only supported 2-way diffs. KDiff3 supports 3-way diffs.

Comment: Thanks. What is the command to do the 3 way diff of the two branches using Kdiff?

Comment: To have Git show you which commit is (or commits are, for rare cases that mean you'll have to do something different) the merge base, use `git merge-base --all <hash1> <hash2>` where the two hash IDs are the two commits that you merged earlier. As long as just one commit hash ID is printed, this is the (single) merge base. How to use those three hashes to fire up your favorite program is a separate issue and depends on the program in question.

Comment: There is no special command when using KDiff3. Install KDiff3 and set that as your diff tool in Git, then simply do `git difftool branch1 branch2`.